# Laravel 5 nested search query

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, orm, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a nested search query but I get this error. I'm trying to search for a company name joined by a company_id.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'company.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `position` where `to_date` >= 2016-06-16 and `company_id` = 123795854693734 and `title` like %searchquery% and `company`.`name` like %searchquery% and `location` like %%)
```

Here is my controller function

```
public function Search(){

    $keyword = Input::get('q');
    $location = Input::get('l');

    $data = Position::where('to_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('company_id', '=', $company_id)
    ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->where('company.name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->where('location', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
    ->orderBy('from_date', 'desc')
    ->paginate(10);

    $data = array(
        'data' => $data,
    );

    return view('myview', $data);

}
```

The model works perfectly. But here it is anyway.

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Position extends Model {
    protected $table = 'position';
    protected $guarded = array("id");
    protected $hidden = array();
    protected $appends = array('local_ad');

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'company_id', 'location'];

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Not too familiar with Laravel, but the error and the code suggest that you're missing a join with the company table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using your relation or joining to the company table actually, that's why it can't find it.

Simply, you can use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method to filter positions with company names.

```
$data = Position::whereHas('company', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
    $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
})->where('to_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
  ->where('company_id', '=', $company_id)
  ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
  ->where('location', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
  ->orderBy('from_date', 'desc')
  ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

This function should be

```php
public function Search(){

    $keyword = Input::get('q');
    $location = Input::get('l');

    $data = Position::where('to_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('company_id', '=', $company_id)
    ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->with(['company' => function( $q ) use ($keyword) {
        ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    }])
    ->where('location', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
    ->orderBy('from_date', 'desc')
    ->paginate(10);

    $data = array(
        'data' => $data,
    );

    return view('myview', $data);
}
```

but this does not do a join, this will fetch position, there is a whereHas in Eloquent, you should explore that also.